# Spring - bean wiring

Tags: spring

Can we wire the bean through jar file, I created Jar file of one of my module and put it into lib directory of WEB-INF folder this jar file contains Action, Bo, DM classes in respective folders, now i am trying to access the to map Action, BO and DM classes in Struts.xml and applicationContaxt.xml file but its giving me an error

Below is a code in Struts.xml file

```
<action name="abc" class="abcAction">
    <result name="success">/jsp/ABC/ABC.jsp</result>
</action>
```

Below is a code in ApplicationContect.xml

```
<bean id="abcAction" class="main.java.com.iws.erik.abc.action.ABCAction"/>
```

I am doing wiring via

```
 <context:annotation-config/>
 <context:component-scan base-package="main.java.com.<projectName>"/>
```

These classes exist in Jar file name ABC.jar but when i am trying to start the server is not able to access those action class and giving below error

> org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'ABCAction': Injection of autowired dependencies failed;

can anybody help me how to map this action file (which is in Jar file) in struts.xml and applicationContext.xml.

Answer (score 2):

Are you sure  package of class    `main.java.com.iws.erik.abc.action`   may be you  confuse ide folder layout with package declaration.May be your package name  `com.iws.erik.abc.action`

Comment: I don't  think this should be a problem until i am givin full path to connect each other while wiring.Its able to read Action class in ApplicationContext but not able to read BO and DM  class even if i am providing same path.now the error is Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException:No matching bean of type [main.java.com.iws.erik.duraPageAlarm.bo.AlarmMasterBO] found for dependency:expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate for this dependency.Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}